# Typescript Sorting based on Enum constants

Tags: typescript, enums

Is it possible to have a list of enums sorted by the order these enums were declared?

```
enum MyEnum {
    VALUE_1,
    VALUE_3,
    VALUE_2
}
```

I create a list in a random order

```
let list = [MyEnum.VALUE_3, MyEnum.VALUE_1, MyEnum.VALUE_2];
```

But it gets ordered as the enum was declared

```
[MyEnum.VALUE_1, MyEnum.VALUE_3, MyEnum.VALUE_2]
```

PS: I really want to know if typescript orders the list out of the box as we have in Java, without having to order it by my own. If I had to order the list by my own I would be prone to errors if the order ever gets changed.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you look at the compiled javascript of your enum:

```
var MyEnum;
(function (MyEnum) {
    MyEnum[MyEnum["VALUE_1"] = 0] = "VALUE_1";
    MyEnum[MyEnum["VALUE_3"] = 1] = "VALUE_3";
    MyEnum[MyEnum["VALUE_2"] = 2] = "VALUE_2";
})(MyEnum || (MyEnum = {}));
```

You'll see that each gets an ordinal number based on the position, so the first is 0 and the last is 2.

If you refer to an enum you'll just get a number back:

```
console.log(MyEnum.VALUE_3); // 1
```

If you want to sort your list:

```
let list = [MyEnum.VALUE_3, MyEnum.VALUE_1, MyEnum.VALUE_2];
console.log(list); // [1, 0, 2]
list.sort((a, b) => a - b);
console.log(list); // [0, 1, 2]
```

If you want the list of the string names of the enum sorted by the ordinal then you can do:

```
let names = list.map(ordinal => MyEnum[ordinal]);
console.log(names); // ["VALUE_1", "VALUE_3", "VALUE_2"]
```

([code in playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=enum%20MyEnum%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20VALUE_1%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20VALUE_3%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20VALUE_2%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20list%20%3D%20%5BMyEnum.VALUE_3%2C%20MyEnum.VALUE_1%2C%20MyEnum.VALUE_2%5D%3B%0D%0Aconsole.log(list)%3B%20%2F%2F%20%5B1%2C%200%2C%202%5D%0D%0Alist.sort((a%2C%20b)%20%3D%3E%20a%20-%20b)%3B%0D%0Aconsole.log(list)%3B%20%2F%2F%20%5B0%2C%201%2C%202%5D%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20names%20%3D%20list.map(ordinal%20%3D%3E%20MyEnum%5Bordinal%5D)%3B%0D%0Aconsole.log(names)%3B%20%2F%2F%20%5B%22VALUE_1%22%2C%20%22VALUE_3%22%2C%20%22VALUE_2%22%5D))

---

#### Edit

You can sort in the same way, regardless of how you set the enum values, you just need to change the [compare function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort).
For example, this will sort the list based on the lexicographical order of the enum string values:

```
enum MyEnum {
    VALUE_1 = "value 1" as any,
    VALUE_3 = "value 3" as any,
    VALUE_2 = "value 2" as any
}

let list = [MyEnum.VALUE_3, MyEnum.VALUE_1, MyEnum.VALUE_2];
console.log(list); // ["value 3", "value 1", "value 2"]
list.sort((a, b) => {
    if (a < b) return -1;
    if (a > b) return 1;
    return 0;
});
console.log(list); // ["value 1", "value 2", "value 3"]

let names = list.map(ordinal => MyEnum[ordinal]);
console.log(names); // ["VALUE_1", "VALUE_2", "VALUE_3"]
```

([code in playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=enum%20MyEnum%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20VALUE_1%20%3D%20%22value%201%22%20as%20any%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20VALUE_3%20%3D%20%22value%203%22%20as%20any%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20VALUE_2%20%3D%20%22value%202%22%20as%20any%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20list%20%3D%20%5BMyEnum.VALUE_3%2C%20MyEnum.VALUE_1%2C%20MyEnum.VALUE_2%5D%3B%0D%0Aconsole.log(list)%3B%20%2F%2F%20%5B%22value%203%22%2C%20%22value%201%22%2C%20%22value%202%22%5D%0D%0Alist.sort((a%2C%20b)%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20if%20(a%20%3C%20b)%20return%20-1%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20if%20(a%20%3E%20b)%20return%201%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%200%3B%0D%0A%7D)%3B%0D%0Aconsole.log(list)%3B%20%2F%2F%20%5B%22value%201%22%2C%20%22value%202%22%2C%20%22value%203%22%5D%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20names%20%3D%20list.map(ordinal%20%3D%3E%20MyEnum%5Bordinal%5D)%3B%0D%0Aconsole.log(names)%3B%20%2F%2F%20%5B%22VALUE_1%22%2C%20%22VALUE_2%22%2C%20%22VALUE_3%22%5D))

---

#### Edit #2

Sorting by the original order of the enum is tricky, you can try:

```
enum MyEnum {
    VALUE_1 = "value 1" as any,
    VALUE_3 = "value 3" as any,
    VALUE_2 = "value 2" as any
}

let list = [MyEnum.VALUE_3, MyEnum.VALUE_1, MyEnum.VALUE_2];
console.log(list); // ["value 3", "value 1", "value 2"]

let sorted = [] as MyEnum[];
let index = 0;
for (let key in MyEnum) {
    if (index % 2 === 0) {
        sorted.push(key as any);
    }

    index++;
}

console.log(sorted); // ["VALUE_1", "VALUE_3", "VALUE_2"]

let names = sorted.map(ordinal => MyEnum[ordinal]);
console.log(names); // ["value 1", "value 3", "value 2"]
```

([code in playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=enum%20MyEnum%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20VALUE_1%20%3D%20%22value%201%22%20as%20any%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20VALUE_3%20%3D%20%22value%203%22%20as%20any%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20VALUE_2%20%3D%20%22value%202%22%20as%20any%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20list%20%3D%20%5BMyEnum.VALUE_3%2C%20MyEnum.VALUE_1%2C%20MyEnum.VALUE_2%5D%3B%0D%0Aconsole.log(list)%3B%20%2F%2F%20%5B%22value%203%22%2C%20%22value%201%22%2C%20%22value%202%22%5D%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20sorted%20%3D%20%5B%5D%20as%20MyEnum%5B%5D%3B%0D%0Alet%20index%20%3D%200%3B%0D%0Afor%20(let%20key%20in%20MyEnum)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20if%20(index%20%25%202%20%3D%3D%3D%200)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20sorted.push(key%20as%20any)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20index%2B%2B%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconsole.log(sorted)%3B%20%2F%2F%20%5B%22VALUE_1%22%2C%20%22VALUE_3%22%2C%20%22VALUE_2%22%5D%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20names%20%3D%20sorted.map(ordinal%20%3D%3E%20MyEnum%5Bordinal%5D)%3B%0D%0Aconsole.log(names)%3B%20%2F%2F%20%5B%22value%201%22%2C%20%22value%203%22%2C%20%22value%202%22%5D))

This seems to work, but you shouldn't count on the order which is received in the for/in loop, unless you don't care about cross-browser behavior (or to be specific explorer support), you can [read about it in MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete#Cross-browser_notes).

Comment: Is there a way to achieve this if the enum is declared with strings instead of numbers. Using `VALUE_1 = <any>'VALUE_1'`

Comment: Sure thing. Check my revised answer

Comment: That doesn't work the way I need it to work. It will order the array using the given value, so you will have `// ["value 1", "value 2", "value 3"]`. But I want to have it ordered the same it was declared i.e.  `// ["value 1", "value 3", "value 2"]`. Is that possible? (Good answer though)

Comment: Revised my answer again

Answer (score 57):

Had the same problem just now. This is my solution:

```
enum Weekday {
  MONDAY = 'MONDAY',
  TUESDAY = 'TUESDAY',
  WEDNESDAY = 'WEDNESDAY',
  THURSDAY = 'THURSDAY',
  FRIDAY = 'FRIDAY',
  SATURDAY = 'SATURDAY',
  SUNDAY = 'SUNDAY'
}

const weekdayOrder = Object.values(Weekday);

const weekdaysToBeSorted = [Weekday.TUESDAY, Weekday.MONDAY, Weekday.FRIDAY];

const sortedWeekdays = weekdaysToBeSorted
  .sort((a, b) => weekdayOrder.indexOf(a) - weekdayOrder.indexOf(b))
```

([TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYOwrgtgBA6swGsAmBDAnlA3gKClAsgPIByAIgIICaUAvFAORFlX0A0uUAKgKoCiAyhWp16PAULYcYvUsXFVaDabPmVJeTgAluAJUEKRW3frXs8AMR0BJIYvqWbLM1H7keO2yNfuJz-t2ZhBn9A+mwAX2xsAGMAexAAZwAXKAB3eGR0QgAnJGBsxUIAIwArYGikgDoANxQAGzBgBIAKOERUNABKAG4ouMSU9Pb0BM5YgCFgfljspOAkRQBtNsy0SrETVlgMjsqmIS2V3YchAF1emPjkqASZuaQjkcUh1dGJqbv5jkrb2ebmlBbIqdWgAPjSOyyuXylQAliA8gAPQgAMwBIIAtBDhmgcnlsnCEcBkWjgZ0OJdErE6sBKnVYgBzZq-e6PNAJTpAA))

Answer (score 5):

Here is another solution. This would prevent flaws even if other contributors to your code change the order of the enum.

```
enum Action {
    EAT = 'EAT',
    PLAY = 'PLAY',
    SING = 'SING',
    SLEEP = 'SLEEP',
}

const actionOrder = {
    [Action.SING] : 1,
    [Action.PLAY] : 2,
    [Action.EAT] : 3,
    [Action.SLEEP] : 4,  
} as const;

const users = [{
    "name": "Mike",
    "action": Action.EAT
}, {
    "name": "John",
    "action": Action.SLEEP
}, {
    "name": "Harry",
    "action": Action.PLAY
}
];

users.sort((a,b) => {
    return actionOrder[a.action] - actionOrder[b.action];
});

console.log(users);
```

Answer (score -4):

I figured out this and tested in my app:

```
export enum OrderState {
    New = '正在申请',
    Acting = '正在阅读',
    Completed = '书已归还',
    Rejected = '被拒申请',
    Cancelled = '撤销申请',
    Lost = '书已遗失'
}

export namespace OrderState {
    export function sort(list: OrderState[]) {
        const sorted = [];
        for (let key of Object.keys(OrderState)) {
            const defined = OrderState[key];
            for (let item of list) {
                if (item == defined) sorted.push(item);
            }
        }

        return sorted;
    }
}


let list:OrderState[] = [OrderState.Rejected, OrderState.New, OrderState.Lost]; 
let sorted = OrderState.sort(list);
console.log(sorted);
```

output: ["正在申请", "被拒申请", "书已遗失"]