# How to ensure enum order in graphql

Tags: typescript, enums, typegraphql

I defined enum named by BlocksType **in server**

```
export enum BlocksType {
    TEXT = "TEXT",
    LINK = "LINK",
    GALLERY = "GALLERY",
    CONTACT = "CONTACT",
    EMAIL = "EMAIL",
    RESIDENCE = "RESIDENCE",
    SNS = "SNS",
}
```

TEXT is the first and SNS is the last. **(This order must be guaranteed.)**

And if you look at the generated types when I was codegen in the client,

```
export enum BlocksType {
  CONTACT = "CONTACT",
  EMAIL = "EMAIL",
  GALLERY = "GALLERY",
  LINK = "LINK",
  RESIDENCE = "RESIDENCE",
  SNS = "SNS",
  TEXT = "TEXT",
}
```

It is probably arranged in alphabetical order.

So, How can I arrange in the order of enum defined in server in client?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Typescript Sorting based on Enum constants](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40085998/typescript-sorting-based-on-enum-constants)

Answer (score 0):

##### Suggested alternative

Assuming you're using [`graphql-code-generator`](https://github.com/dotansimha/graphql-code-generator), [this collaborator's comment](https://github.com/dotansimha/graphql-code-generator/issues/6935#issuecomment-961867985) suggests using a `Query` to expose the data in the correct order, since `Object.values()` apparently is not guaranteed to always yield the same order.

In your case, something like the following should work.

```
type Query {
  blockTypes: [BlockType!]!
}
```

##### The actual answer

Knowing the `Object.values()` caveat, it should be fine (most of the time) to simply [disable sorting](https://github.com/dotansimha/graphql-code-generator/issues/6935#issuecomment-955181724):

```yaml
# codegen.yml
schema: "schema.graphql"
config:
  sort: false
...
```

```
// codegen.ts
export default {
  schema: 'schema.graphql',
  config: {
    ...
    sort: false,
  },
  ...
};
```

Keep in mind this will disable all sorting in the generated schemas/type files, but (at least for me) that doesn't seem to have any undesired side-effects.

Answer (score 0):

It's an unwanted (in my opinion) behavior of `lexicographicSortSchema` from [lexicographicSortSchema](https://github.com/graphql/graphql-js/blob/main/src/utilities/lexicographicSortSchema.ts#L41) from [graphql](https://github.com/graphql/graphql-js/blob/main/src/utilities/lexicographicSortSchema.ts#L41)

Enum values should not be sorted alphabetically. The original order should be preserved.

See more info at https://github.com/dotansimha/graphql-code-generator/issues/6935#issuecomment-1474084101 - there you may also find a patch for graphql which can be applied with [patch-package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/patch-package).